# How can I automatically release resources RAII-style in Perl?

Tags: perl, raii

Say I have a resource (e.g. a filehandle or network socket) which has to be freed:

```
open my $fh, "<", "filename" or die "Couldn't open filename: $!";
process($fh);
close $fh or die "Couldn't close filename: $!";
```

Suppose that `process` might die. Then the code block exits early, and `$fh` doesn't get closed.

I could explicitly check for errors:

```
open my $fh, "<", "filename" or die "Couldn't open filename: $!";
eval {process($fh)};
my $saved_error = $@;
close $fh or die "Couldn't close filename: $!";
die $saved_error if $saved_error;
```

but this kind of code is notoriously difficult to get right, and only gets more complicated when you add more resources.

In C++ I would use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to create an object which owns the resource, and whose destructor would free it. That way, I don't have to remember to free the resource, and resource cleanup happens correctly as soon as the RAII object goes out of scope - even if an exception is thrown. Unfortunately in Perl a `DESTROY` method is unsuitable for this purpose as there are no guarantees for when it will be called.

Is there a Perlish way to ensure resources are automatically freed like this even in the presence of exceptions? Or is explicit error checking the only option?

Comment: Perl uses reference counting, not a 'real' garbage collector, so it is deterministic. You just have to make sure your guard object doesn't get stored somewhere else. This is done by simply not passing it to any function or using it in any way ;-).

Comment: @Leon I was about to make the same argument but then I noticed http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html#Destructors : *Perl's notion of the right time to call a destructor is not well-defined currently, which is why your destructors should not rely on when they are called.*

Comment: For what it's worth, your example is a bad one, because `$fh` will be closed when it goes out of scope to begin with; lexical filehandles are implicitly RAII.

Comment: @ Sinan Ünür: Theoretically you are right, in practice I've yet to see a case where it doesn't work as expected. The part that I think it non-deterministic is the order with which different variables are destroyed.

Comment: @hobbs: filehandles aren't really special. They too are refcounted and have their own (built-in) destructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's what [Scope::Guard](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Scope::Guard) was designed to help with.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Scope::Guard;

my $filename = 'file.test';

open my $fh, '>', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open '$filename': $!";

{
    my $sg = Scope::Guard->new(
        sub {
            close $fh or die "Could not close";
            warn "file closed properly\n";
        }
    );

    process($fh);
}

sub process { die "cannot process\n" }
```

However, as @Philip notes in the comments, `Scope::Guard` utilizes the `DESTROY` method which creates some uncertainty as to when the scope exit code will be run. Modules such as `Hook::Scope` and `Sub::ScopeFinalizer` look fine as well although I have never used them.

I do like [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try::Tiny) for its clean interface and sheer simplicity and it will help you handle exceptions the correct way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Try::Tiny;

my $filename = 'file.test';

open my $fh, '>', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open '$filename': $!";

try {
    process($fh);
}
catch {
    warn $_;
}
finally {
    close $fh
        and warn "file closed properly\n";
};

sub process { die "cannot process\n" }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. But since it uses the `DESTROY` method doesn't it mean that it's at the whim of the garbage collector rather than deterministically working when the scope exits? I think `Sub::ScopeFinalizer` or `Hook::Scope` (linked from `Scope::Guard`) are closer to what I want.

Comment: Perl uses reference counting, not a 'real' garbage collector, so it is deterministic.

Comment: Looking more carefully, Hook::Scope, Hook::Lexwrap, Sub::ScopeFinalizer and Scope::OnExit either use a `sub DESTROY` or an XS `SAVEDESTRUCTOR_X`. If there's a way to do this without destructors, I haven't found one.

Comment: SAVEDESTRUCTOR_X is a very different mechanism than sub DESTROY. It is directly tied to the scope, and thus entirely deterministical. They execute in LIFO order.

Comment: @Leon and @Philip which is why I really liked `Scope::OnExit` and I think the OP might still be best served by using that module.

Comment: @Leon, thanks, that's great to know. For reference: `Scope::OnExit` and `Hook::Scope` use `SAVEDESTRUCTOR_X`. `Sub::ScopeFinalizer`, `Scope::Guard` and `Hook::LexWrap` use `sub DESTROY`.

Comment: See also the perl.com article "Better Code Through Destruction", at http://www.perl.com/lpt/a/993

Answer (score 4):

My module [Scope::OnExit](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scope::OnExit) is intended for exactly that.

Comment: Yes, it's nice, but it depends on the destructor which perltoot states is not called deterministically. Even if the GC "really is" deterministic, it is not documented as being deterministic. I'd rather not rely on undocumented behaviour.

Comment: No, it does NOT depend on a destructor in fact

Answer (score 3):

The nice thing about lexical filehandles is that they'll get closed (and freed) when they go out of scope. So you can just do something like this:

```
{
    # bare block creates new scope
    open my $fh, "<", "filename" or die "Couldn't open filename: $!";
    eval { process($fh) };

    # handle exceptions here

    close $fh or die "Couldn't close filename: $!";
}

# $fh is now out of scope and goes away automagically.
```